# How to access a hidden text field in a WebView using XCUITest for iOS automation?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, xctest, xcuitest

There is a hidden text field in the Web View that pop up in the Native app.
Below is the hidden field design :

`<span class="session-id" tabindex="-1"><input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" data-testid="session-id" id="session-id" placeholder="session-id" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" type="text"></span>`

There is another text field inside   which is not hidden and also accessible :
`<div data-testid="InputIdentityFlowValue-container" class="input-wrapper"><input class="input-InputIdentityFlowValue" type="email" autocomplete="email" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" id="InputIdentityFlowValue" data-testid="InputIdentityFlowValue" placeholder="Email Address" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="Email Address" aria-required="true" required="" value=""></div>`

When checked using Safari tool , we are able to identify it in the UI. Need to access this element to pass a value using XCUITest. Tried a lot of querying like XCUIApplication().otherElements, XCUIApplication().webViews.otherElements, descendants, etc etc. But unable to find this text field. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format the HTML nicely and also add what code you have already in your XCUITest.

Comment: Also please provide the debugDescription when viewing this screen.